# Clock on Windows Form without polling?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-3.5

I need to display current time with seconds on my form. My clock must display seconds and im afraid about performance.

1. Is there any method without polling? (some system event or something?)
2. If there is no method without polling - shall i use `Date().getTime()` to get current time in my timer tick event?

Comment: What are you talking about? Do you mean polling?

Comment: Sorry, my english is not the best...  I corrected this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and display `DateTime.Now` in each tick.

Comment: +1. @Kamil, generally to measure/display/record some event you need to do it at frequency that is at least [twice higher than event's frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_rate). So 500ms would be theoretically better. But since it it perception/performance question it is up to you to try and decide.